# Erasing the contents of a photocopier hard drive, in such a way that the copier can use it again

Tags: sensitive-data-exposure

http://www.idtheftcenter.org/Identity-Theft/photocopying-sensitive-documents-you-might-want-to-think-again.html

How do I erase the copier hard drive if I take it out, without damaging it so the copier could use it again?

Do I have to take the whole thing apart, or is there an easier way (cable etc)?

This is for a HP Envy 5540 copier.

Comment: You should at least mention the brand and model of the copier if you want someone to help you.

Comment: The brand and model is HP Envy 5540

Comment: I'm guessing that most consumer-grade copiers do not have storage that would hold onto documents in this way.

Comment: They seem to have a hard drive https://bucks.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/06/01/why-photocopiers-have-hard-drives/

Comment: Related question: [How to handle decomissioned/donated/RMAed printers?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/86772/32746)

Answer (score 1):

There's no other way. Open up the copier, take the hard drive out, use the linux shred command and the copier will be able to use it again.

Comment: *Depending on the device*, this may make the copier unusable without restoring then some files required by the device. Manufacturer's support should be able to tell.